# How to loop through multiple data frames to select a data frame based on row criteria?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, loops, dataframe

I have a few Python dataframes in Pandas, I want to loop through them to find out which data frame meet my rows' criteria and save it in a new data frame.

```
d = {'Count' : ['10', '11', '12', '13','13.4','12.5']}
df_1= pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df_1

d = {'Count' : ['10', '-11', '-12', '13','16','2']}
df_2= pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df_2
```

Here is the logic I want to use, but it does not contain the right syntax,

```
for df in (df_1,df_2)
    if df['Count'][0] >0 and df['Count'][1] >0 and df['Count'][2]>0 and df['Count'][3]>0 
    and (df['Count'][4] is between df['Count'][3]+0.5 and df['Count'][3]-0.5) is True:
        df.save
```

The correct output is **df_1...** because it meets my condition. How do I create a new `DataFrame` or `LIST` to save the result as well?

[image]

Comment: What’s the issue, exactly? Your pseudocode looks fine, why haven’t you written it in Python?

Comment: Not sure why people are voting you down. You provided a clear question, with sample data, and mentioned your current code is throwing syntax errors. I'll provide an answer shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me know if you have any questions in the comments. Main updates I made to your code was:

1. Replacing your [chained indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) with `.loc`
2. Consolidating your first few separate `and`'d comparisons into a comparison on a slice of the series, reduced down to a single T/F with `.all()`

Code below:

```
import pandas as pd 

# df_1 & df_2 input taken from you
d = {'Count' : ['10', '11', '12', '13','13.4','12.5']}
df_1= pd.DataFrame(data=d)

d = {'Count' : ['10', '-11', '-12', '13','16','2']}
df_2= pd.DataFrame(data=d)

# my solution here
df_1['Count'] = df_1['Count'].astype('float')
df_2['Count'] = df_2['Count'].astype('float')

my_dataframes = {'df_1': df_1, 'df_2': df_2}
good_dataframes = []
for df_name, df in my_dataframes.items():
    if (df.loc[0:3, 'Count'] > 0).all() and (df.loc[3,'Count']-0.5 <= df.loc[4, 'Count'] <= df.loc[3, 'Count']+0.5):
        good_dataframes.append(df_name)

good_dataframes_df = pd.DataFrame({'good': good_dataframes})
```

TEST:

```
>>> print(good_dataframes_df)
   good
0  df_1
```

Comment: I prefer to have a list of the dataframes' name, which is df_1....df4....df5, for those that qualify , in a LIST or Dataframe, i provided a screenshot

Comment: updated my answer in response to the `good` df screenshot posted in your question update

Comment: in fact , my actual criteria is complex, when I add OR in the if condition, how to put the right indent for opening a new line for a longer if condition?

Comment: I'm a little confused by your last question. You can have an `or` in the boolean just like there's an `and` in my answer. your indent question sounds like a different issue possibly based on how your code editor handles whitespace or line breaks. if you post another reproduceable example as a new question, you can link to it here and I'll take a look.

Comment: never mind, i posted a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59586706/python-break-down-a-super-long-if-statement/59587257#59587257