# Python break down a super long IF statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, if-statement

How to simplify or break down the super long IF Condition in Python pandas?

```
my_dataframes = {'d1': d1, 'd2': d2,'d3': d3}
good_dataframes = []
for df_name, df in my_dataframes.items():
    if ((df.loc[1:4, 'test'] <= 6).all() 
        and (df.loc[5:9, 'dif'] < 9).all()) or ((df.loc[1:5, 'test'] <= 6).all() 
                                                      and (df.loc[5:8, 'dif'] < 8).all()) or ((df.loc[1:8, 'test'] <= 6).all() 
                                                                                                    and (df.loc[5:8, 'dif'] < 9).all()):
        good_dataframes.append(df_name)
```

the challenge for me is put the right indent

Comment: Define a function that does it.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not an expert to define a function, please advise

Comment: @PyBoss it's `def myFunction():` and then a tabbed newline and `return ...` where ... is the long expression you have.  Then `if(myFunction())` which is much shorter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can break down in 3 major check functions:

```
my_dataframes = {'d1': d1, 'd2': d2,'d3': d3}

def check_1(df):
    return (df.loc[1:4, 'test'] <= 6).all() and (df.loc[5:9, 'dif'] < 9).all()

def check_2(df):
    return (df.loc[1:5, 'test'] <= 6).all() and (df.loc[5:8, 'dif'] < 8).all()

def check_3(df):
    return (df.loc[1:8, 'test'] <= 6).all() and (df.loc[5:8, 'dif'] < 9).all()

CHECK_FUNCTIONS = (check_1, check_2, check_3)

def check(df):
    return any(check_f(df) for check_f in CHECK_FUNCTIONS)

good_dataframes = []
for df_name, df in my_dataframes.items():

    if  check(df):
        good_dataframes.append(df_name)
```

to obtain good_dataframes you can use a list comprehension:

```
good_dataframes = [df_name for df_name, df in my_dataframes.items() if check(df)]
```

Comment: Like your answer the most coz I have lots of IF statement to put in every function, and any function works will meet me need

Answer (score 3):

Define a function that contains the conditions.

```
def is_good_df(df):
    return (((df.loc[1:4, 'test'] <= 6).all()
             and (df.loc[5:9, 'dif'] < 9).all())
            or ((df.loc[1:5, 'test'] <= 6).all()
                and (df.loc[5:8, 'dif'] < 8).all())
            or ((df.loc[1:8, 'test'] <= 6).all()
                and (df.loc[5:8, 'dif'] < 9).all()))
```

A good IDE should help with getting the indentation right.

Notice that you were also missing the `()` after some of your `.all` calls.

Then you can do

```
my_dataframes = {'d1': d1, 'd2': d2,'d3': d3}
good_dataframes = [df_name for df, df_name in my_dataframes.items() if is_good_df(df)]
```

Answer (score 1):

would this make it more understandable:

```
my_dataframes = {'d1': d1, 'd2': d2,'d3': d3}
good_dataframes = []
for df_name, df in my_dataframes.items():
    if ((df.loc[1:4, 'test'] <= 6).all and (df.loc[5:9, 'dif'] < 9).all()) or 
       ((df.loc[1:5, 'test'] <= 6).all and (df.loc[5:8, 'dif'] < 8).all()) or 
       ((df.loc[1:8, 'test'] <= 6).all and (df.loc[5:8, 'dif'] < 9).all()):
        good_dataframes.append(df_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put your `and` expressions in a list and then check if [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) of the values is `True` (matches with your `or` logic):

```py
my_dataframes = {'d1': d1, 'd2': d2,'d3': d3}
good_dataframes = []
for df_name, df in my_dataframes.items():
    conds = [(df.loc[1:4, 'test'] <= 6).all and (df.loc[5:9, 'dif'] < 9).all(),
             (df.loc[1:5, 'test'] <= 6).all and (df.loc[5:8, 'dif'] < 8).all(),
             (df.loc[1:8, 'test'] <= 6).all and (df.loc[5:8, 'dif'] < 9).all()]
    if any(conds):
        good_dataframes.append(df_name)
```

Comment: Yes @PyBoss , this is done through the `any` function. In my answer it is a link you can read more about it there

Answer (score 0):

You can use the logical operation like and, or etc.

```
`my_dataframes = {'d1': d1, 'd2': d2,'d3': d3} good_dataframes = [] for df_name, df in my_dataframes.items():
    conds = [(df.loc[1:4, 'test'] <= 6).all and (df.loc[5:9, 'dif'] < 9).all(),
             (df.loc[1:5, 'test'] <= 6).all and (df.loc[5:8, 'dif'] < 8).all(),
             (df.loc[1:8, 'test'] <= 6).all and (df.loc[5:8, 'dif'] < 9).all()]
    if any(conds):
        good_dataframes.append(df_name)
```

`